# Comparing Performance in Python: equal versus non equal

Tags: python, performance, comparison, equals

When comparing any variable, there is the choice of comparing equality versus comparing inequality. For variables with one element, *not a string/list/tuple/etc...*, the difference is probably either non-existent or negligible.

**The Question:**
When comparing two multi-element variables, is checking whether they are equal slower or faster than comparing whether they are not equal.

My gut is telling me comparing whether they are not equal should be faster. I'm curious if anybody can tell me if this is true, and for which types of multi-element types this is so.

***Note***: I have looked, and haven't found any posts here that answers my question. It might just be obvious, but I'd like to have more opinions than just my own.

Comment: Specifically for comparing multi-element variables with other multi-element variables.

Comment: You could try profiling.

Comment: What's a "multi-element variable"?

Comment: @IsmailBadawi I will, and will post the results. But the second reason why I ask this question here, other than getting an answer, is to find out if there is any (un)official documentation or research done for this topic.

Comment: theoretically, I would say that your guts are wrong. They are probably assuming that to check equality you have to check every item, while to check difference, you can stop at any different item. But if you look at concrete example, you'll see that for a given value, you'll have to check every element until you find one that is different. What is true on the other hand, is that asserting that 2 different elements are different is faster than asserting that 2 equal elements are equal. But that's not related to the method

Comment: @delnan A list of other variables/constants. For instance a tuple or a dictionary.

Comment: Depends. Do your objects implement `__eq__` or `__ne__` methods? If not, *there won't be a difference*. If they do, then *performance is directly correlated* to how those special methods perform.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could always just check:

```
>>> timeit("{'a': 1, 'b': 2} == {'a': 2, 'b': 1}")
0.29072967777517983
>>> timeit("{'a': 1, 'b': 2} != {'a': 2, 'b': 1}")
0.2906114293159803
```

The difference seems to be negligible ... another test case perhaps?

```
>>> timeit("range(30) == range(35)")
0.7179841181163837
>>> timeit("range(30) != range(35)")
0.725536848004765
```

Again, negligible.

```
>>> timeit("a == b", "a = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}; b = {'a': 2, 'b': 1}")
0.06806470555693522
>>> timeit("a != b", "a = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}; b = {'a': 2, 'b': 1}")
0.06724365965146717
```

And with the object creation moved out.  Admittedly small examples, but still, I imagine both use short-circuiting where appropriate when it becomes obvious that they differ.

Comment: I'm creating a test with longer lists to get the difference up. Comparing a dicts with length 2 won't show a difference. Thanks tho ;)

Comment: this test includes the object build time, it would be interesting to move that part to setup= and retest.

Comment: Good poing @tdelaney, and included in the output.

Comment: The results I'm getting seem to suggest that there is no real difference between the two for lists and dicts. Though I suspect that may be due to the overly-random nature of my generated lists. 
I should check this on 'real world lists'.

@g.d.d.c Not knowing exactly how timeit() works I opted to create two dicts and compare them in a callable.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is directly in correlation with `object.__eq__()` and `object.__ne__`.

This methods are launched when you use `==` (equal) or `!=`(non-equal) and in function of objects you want to compare it could be faster or slower depending of how the method is written.

See [Datamodel Basic customization](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#basic-customization) in official doc.

Comment: I think it's worthwhile reading though, as the implementations of those functions on the classes he's comparing could have significant effect.

Comment: This is eventually what it all boils down to, but instead of me plowing through the code on my own I thought I'd start an exchange to create a set of ideas and tests to explain the difference *(if any)*... I thank you for pointing this out anyway, this gives a place to start looking for people who are wondering the same thing!

Answer (score -3):

My experience with some Cortex M3 assembly (or at least my professors say that's what it is), is that when you check equality or non-equality, there is one compare command that sets up 3 bits, and one if statement (if you can call it that), which looks at a particular one. Essentially you compare `A` and `B`, the 3 bits are Smaller, Equal and Bigger, then when you check anything it should be either checking if it is either bigger or smaller (2 checks, so 2 cycles) for non-equality, or applying a NOT to the equality flag, which depending on the architecture may be 2 different actions or a single cycle. Thus I speculate that it depends on compilers, assemblers and the CPU's architecture.

This however should mean that you can make two programs, each making an immense amount of such checks, and time their execution, where immense would run into the tens of thousands (judging by execution times in C/C++). In my humble opinion this is a fairly feasible task, which can be timed by hand so you don't mess with timers, and as timers have some peculiarities as to their precision in many languages, they might not even catch the execution time of single statements. Or you can time the immense loops and see what the computer says.

Keep in mind however that if you get 1.1x time in the not-equal loop, this does not mean that inequality takes 1.1x the time of equality checks, as the loop has a far bigger cycle, it will probably be 2x the time. With more tests with more checks per loop it should be very easy to determine the time it takes for the loop and the time spent on the checks. Hope this helps.

Comment: This is a very interesting discussion, but unfortunately it has very little to do with (non-)equality tests *in Python*. Both tests translate to a call to a free-form method that may do anything, and almost always does far more than just doing a single hardware-level integer comparison.

Comment: I do state within my reply that it mostly comes down to interpreters, compilers, assemblers, anything between code and execution, I hoped to offer some insight to some deeper aspects, and I hope/believe that the solution I offered with the loops and timing them is high level enough to include all the intermediate factors into the calculation, so as to prevent us from pondering over the complexities of how the process is implemented.

Comment: @user3079666 And I thank you for your contribution! Realizing that there are more things at work than just Python being Python is a noteworthy thing. My question though, springs forth from Python's ability to work with lists/arrays, and how far the optimization goes.

Comment: I think I now start to better understand the question, and it probably has to do with data structures as a subject, in which I am not well versed... however I must agree with your gut in that if a structure is different, it is most probably different before the end, thus the difference should be found in the middle of scanning the two structures, whereas seeing if they are identical requires you to always scan the entire structure..I believe that's all I can contribute, if I find any very good pythonista in the department I will forward the question to him.I enjoyed thinking it through though!